# Blank Security Warning when Opening Website in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I get a blank security warning popup window when trying to open a website, in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. It worked on my other computer in the same environment.

I moves the files to a new fresh computer and I get this window.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Nothing is clickable, even what where the buttons should be. Visual Studio is just frozen, can't even close the IDE nor the popup window. It doesn't happen to Web Projects, only websites.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: It is possible that Azure is trying to confirm an account or login. Maybe check your account (if you have one) using the website? Or log into your Live ID form a website before accessing the site, see if that helps get past the prompt.

Comment: @Dr.AaronDishno I'll try to login o hotmail in Explorer and check.

Comment: @Dr.AaronDishno Nope, get the same warning. It happens for websites, not Web Projects. Maybe there is a way to disable security warning globally?

Comment: Good Luck, I will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @Dr.AaronDishno came across this one, seems like my problem, but can't understand if they solve it or not: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3064f10b-af5f-4a4a-b91d-6ad728541e4f/unable-to-open-solution-security-warning-freeze?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: Unsolved. May want to try reloading VS.

Comment: @Dr.AaronDishno I tried, reloading, restarting, etc. Nothing helped. Meanwhile I am installing VS 2013.

Answer (score 9):

I got the same issue. Just fixed it. In my case it was entity ".tt" files fault. I guess for some reason VS 2015 does not recognize ".tt" extension. I've just deleted these files and run website (not web application) successfully

Comment: Thank goodness for StackOverflow!  This solved it for me.  I have no idea what the .tt files are, but I'll soon find out, I guess!

Comment: tt stands for t4 templates which are needed by Entity Framework model to classes conversions

Answer (score 0):

The .tt files are needed if using Entity Framework.

Here is my workaround that worked in two cases of the blank security warning.  Rename the files with .tt extension to .tt.old.

Open the project (it will not compile, so don't try)
Save and close the project
Rename the .tt.old files back to their original names
Open the project again, this time the warning will have content and will be clickable.